# Filter element stored in variable by class

Tags: jquery

I have an elements stored in a variable (var body). These elements take the form of:

```
<p class='txt'></p> or <p class='img'></p>
```

I would like pass 'body' into a function and only return the element passed into it if its class is 'img'.

Comment: please show us what you've already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
$(body).hasClass('img');
```

or maybe:

```
$(body).filter('.img');
```